# TypeError: jQuery.subscribe is not a function on shopware5

Tags: shopware

I have created a custom theme on shopware5 using the "Bare" theme as the parent theme. I have added "Jquery" library on my theme.

However, I am getting "TypeError: jQuery.subscribe is not a function" Error when I load some pages on the site.

I can see there is no such an issue when I switch back to the Responsive theme.

I need to use a image zoom plugin on my detail page but I am unable to setup the plugin because of this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JS file should be included in the Theme.php file of your theme.
Example:

```
protected $extend = 'Responsive';
... 
protected $javascript = array(
        'src/js/jquery.my-js-file.js',
    );
...
protected $name = <<<'SHOPWARE_EOD' ...
```

Then you shouls clear caches and compile your theme. After that you can use your library.